# SvnNotify: svn log message gets bad chars when executed from hook but not from the command line

Tags: linux, svn, hook

When I execute my svn post-commit hook from the command line I get the SVN log message well formatted. When I execute it from the hook (real commit test) I get the log message with bad charset. Looked everywhere but I cannot figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

My post commit script:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
CS="UTF-8"
USERS="blahblah@gmail.com"

svnnotify --charset $CS --svn-encoding $CS --css-inline --repos-path "$1" --revision "$2" --subject-prefix "[SuperProj-Commit]-" --to $USERS --handler HTML::ColorDiff -d
```

I get this:

```
[SuperProj-Commit]-[48] - testando acentua?\195?\167?\195?\163o!
```

In the subject line and in the body of the message as well. The problem is ONLY in the svn log message. Characters showing up in the diff are showing up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install your language locale here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=196414

Then do inside your post-commit:

```
export LANG=your_new_locale
```

To list the locales available in your linux system you can do:

```
locale -a
```